# Как вытащить данные из сайта?

Tags: c#, ip

Всем привет, есть сайт http://www.myip.ru/ru-RU/index.php , нужно с него вытащить IP, и добавить в переменную, но я не знаю как это сделать... и даже толком не знаю как сделать запрос к гуглу... кто может помогите.

Comment: 1. Чтобы IP не "вытаскивать", используйте то, что проще: [http://checkip.dyndns.org/][1]
 2. Сделать HTTP запрос: [WebClient.DownloadString()][2]


  [1]: http://checkip.dyndns.org/
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144200(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.externalip.net/ip/"));
```